# Problem with importing new Mongo database into the server

Tags: django, mongodb, ssh, server

I have a Django-based website on the server. I am not really professional at this btw!
So, I started the website on the server showing some data from MongoDB.
This time I would like to change the DB to the newer one. This is what I am doing:

First I drop the last DB: (On venv):

```
$ mongo <db_name> --eval 'db.aggregation__class.drop'
```

Then I scp (the new db) JSON-exported file into a server directory.
Then I call the mongo to activate that new db:

```
$ mongoimport --db <new db name> --collection <new db collection name> --file <server directory>
```

I also checked if the db is activated by this:

```
$ mongo <new db name> --eval
```

And it is working.

The problem is when I am calling it in the views.py, it does not show that it is connecting to the new db. Consider the fact that it was working with the last db!

views.py

```
# connect to MongoDb Database
myclient = MongoClient(port=27017)
mydatabase = myclient[db_name]
classagg = mydatabase['aggregation__class']
database_text = classagg.find()
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is 'aggregation__class' the new collection name?

Comment: You don't need to drop the collection. Use option `--drop` in the `mongoimport` command

Comment: Try `mongoimport --db=<new db name> --collection=<new db collection name> ...`

Comment: @Joe Yes 'aggregation__class' is the new collection name

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks! you are right!